# MySQL table sets empty spaces to Â despite collation of utf8_general_ci

Tags: php, mysql

Â is being inserted from textareas with empty space at beginning into MySQL table, despite having the database and table set to collation of utf8_general_ci.

I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the head of the page doing the inserts.  I haven't experienced this problem with other databases/tables on the same MySQL installation, and these are set to the default collation of latin1_swedish_ci.

I can resolve the issue with `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` after the MySQL connection is established, however I'd like to know why this happens despite setting the table to utf-8 and having the charset to utf-8 in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice it before, but the textareas contained `&nbsp;`  Removing that fixes the issue and I don't need to use `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly initialize the connection with `utf8` unless you can set a default somehow, which means `SET NAMES` is mandatory.

If you're using some 1990s style `mysql_query` based application that opens and closes connections at random points in your code base, without any proper framework, you might have a hard time tracking these all down.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain why I don't need to do this with other databases/tables on the same installation.  Also I'm using trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['macroscopic'])); so there shouldn't be any white spaces...

Comment: Those aren't white spaces, but they could be [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). You should be doing `trim` *before* escaping in any case. Like I said, unless the connection defaults are `utf8`, you will have to specify it every time. This is [in the documentation on character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html).

Answer (score 0):

your php/html file/s should have utf-8 encoding. your mysql database and table/s as well collation utf-8. however, you can try then to make test inserts from your php file not with submitted html-form-data just to see if it's a php or a html/form/browser problem.